# Mathematical characterization of gravitational geons as reference request, and their properties as main question

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, physics, general-relativity

I've edited (ten days ago) a question on Physics Stack Exchange, this [*Mathematical characterization of gravitational geons*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/726281/mathematical-characterization-of-gravitational-geons), post with identifier **726281** the users of the site were kind adding in the comment thread links about papers related to gravitational geons. And a question on Meta of MathOverflow, identifier **5432** of this [post.](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5432/asking-if-a-post-about-a-mathematical-characterization-of-gravitational-geons-ca) I think that I should to delete both posts if it is edited an answer for this post.

> **Question (Updated after the interesting comments of professor in comments).** Please, can you identify an article and the corresponding equations/formulation (equation and page from the article) characterizing a gravitational geon? Secondly the post has more focus on electromagnetic fields and classical gravity, but I'm interested in the discussion of possible singularities in the solution. Can you tell us, from your knowleges or as a reference request, the properties of these solutions (the gravitational geons)?**Many thanks.**

The companion question is from an advice that was given from kind professors on Meta: (in my words) summarize the more important properties of gravitational geons from your knowledges or from the literature answering my post as a reference request.

I'm not able to read the article but I'm motivated to study your answer.

In Wikipedia is edited the article [*Geon (physics)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics)) of an hypothetical object in theoretical physics, that studied the physicist John Archibald Wheeler. In the post of Physics Stack Exchange were added from kind users comments about references for the literature.

Comment: If you consider suitable add the tags that you consider, (tensor), (differential-geometry), (differential-equations). If you know the equations/formulation of gravitational geons from your knowledges please add these in you answer.

Comment: A refererence from the comment thread of Physics Stack Exchange is *Gravitational Geons Revisited* due to professors Paul R. Anderson and Dieter R. Brill last revised 3 Sep 1997 as the article from arXiv with identifier **gr-qc/9610074**

Comment: Few years ago CORDIS (European Comission), if I refer well, had a project studying gravitational geons as they inform in their web under the epigraph *Localized objects formed by self-trapped gravitational waves* Project GRAVITYWAVESTARS, tab *Results in Brief*

Comment: this question would be better with some focus; there is no unique definition of a geon, generically it is a stable compact field bound by gravity; do you wish to focus on electromagnetic fields and classical gravity? do you allow for singularities in the solution? one precise mathematical result is [Derrick's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00702) --- perhaps that is what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm agree with your critic, but it is due my poor knowledges. I'm going to edit the post, but I feel free to add as companion of your answer general information in a concise way (if it is possible in few paragraphs) for the professors of the site MathOverflow @CarloBeenakker

Comment: I appreciate a lot the upvotes of professors and MO users. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gravitational geon is a space-time configuration that is bounded (asymptotically flat at spatial infinity) and stable (held together for all times by its own gravitational attraction). No such object is believed to exist, a geon should be radiating gravitational waves, lose energy, and decay for long times. No-go theorems exist, see for example [On Derrick's theorem in curved spacetime](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00702).

A simple explanation why the non-linear Klein-Gordon equation in Minkowski 3+1 dimensional spacetime does not support stable, time-independent solutions of finite energy is given in [lecture notes](https://indico.cern.ch/event/951466/contributions/4009710/attachments/2109820/3548883/Aveiro_Set_2020_Lecture_4_final_print.pdf) by Herdeiro (page 7-10).

There are ways to avoid the no-go theorem. Periodic (rather than time-independent) solutions are one possibility ([Q-balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-ball)). The obstruction does not apply to 1+1 dimensions, see [Gravitational geons in 1+1 dimensions.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0611)

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and help with this excellent answer, when I can I'm going to study it.

Comment: With your permission I'm going to add that the history of solutions of Einstein's field  equations is first find the solutions of mathematical equations, secondly imagine a physical mechanism producing this solution, and finally take observations of it; but the  acceptance is delayed: even when the theory tells to physicists about the existence of certain solutions or phenomenon, in my view some physicists take time, years or decades, to accept the existence of counterintuitive objects, they prefer observe these objects directly with experiments or instruments before that they believe in these

Comment: I think that you answer is excellent, I'm going to pay the bounty, and when I can I'm going to accept the answer. You're very kindly (my concern are my speculations about this subject, but that now I prefer don't add here). Thanks you so much.